# AWS ECS: how to change estimated EC2 instance warm-up in the scaling policy when using a capacity provider

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs

I use a capacity provider with an Auto Scaling Group (ASG). The scaling policy (AutoScaling-ECSManagedAutoScalingPlan) in the ASG is managed by the capacity provider.

Is it possible to change the estimated [instance warm-up parameter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-scaling-simple-step.html#as-step-scaling-warmup) in an ASG scaling policy? I tried to create a scaling policy in terraform but it's not used when the capacity provider is applied.

Comment: Can you please provide the code you tried to use and any errors?

Comment: Tell please can i change estimated instance warm up when using capacity provider when asg managed by them

Comment: I don't have any errors but i can't change estimated warm up in asg when using capacity provider when asg become  ECSManaged . It's possible to change warm up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using capacity provider, it takes over the ASG scaling policy and injects it's own.

You cannot change it when the provider is used

Comment: For more information see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/asg-capacity-providers.html